# Wrong size in Qt widget + widget updage issue

Tags: linux, qt, widget, size, show

Here is a pruned version of a problem I have using QT/linux.  The program runs, but the size of the displayed widget is wrong (the contents, frame + labels, does not fit).

I understood that the size of a windows should be computed fron its contents (children).  Why is that not happening properly here?

So the first question is, of course why this is happening.

The real program actually updates the contents of the widget at run-time. I have tried to simulate that behavior by the insertion of the `main_window->show()` (commented `//SHOW1`). If this first `show()` call is made, then the second `show()` does not show the new contents the widget. I have tried with update without success...

```
 #include <QApplication>
 #include <QtCore>
 #include <QMainWindow>
 #include <QTabWidget>
 #include <QWidget>
 #include <QGroupBox>
 #include <QVBoxLayout>
 #include <QLabel>

 #include <stdlib.h>


 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     QMainWindow* main_window = new(QMainWindow);
    main_window->setObjectName("main_window");
    main_window->resize(800, 600);
    main_window->setWindowTitle("Hello");

    QTabWidget* node_tab_widget = new QTabWidget(main_window);
 //    node_tab_widget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
 //    node_tab_widget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
    node_tab_widget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("tab_widget"));
    node_tab_widget->resize(500, 400);

     QWidget* w= new QWidget(node_tab_widget);
     node_tab_widget->addTab(w, "TAB");

     //main_window->show();  //SHOW1
     QGroupBox* group_widget = new QGroupBox("GROUPNAME", w);
     QVBoxLayout*  group_layout = new QVBoxLayout;
     group_widget->setLayout(group_layout);
     group_layout->addWidget((QLabel*)new QLabel(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>here1"));
     group_layout->addWidget((QLabel*)new QLabel("here2"));
 //     group_widget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);


     main_window->update();
     main_window->show();
     return app.exec();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what is the result you expect, can be something like what you get from this code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTabWidget>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

 QApplication app(argc, argv);
 QMainWindow* main_window = new(QMainWindow);
 main_window->setObjectName("main_window");
 main_window->resize(800, 600);
 main_window->setWindowTitle("Hello");

 QTabWidget* node_tab_widget = new QTabWidget();
 node_tab_widget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("tab_widget"));
 node_tab_widget->resize(500, 400);

 QWidget* w= new QWidget();
 node_tab_widget->addTab(w, "TAB");

 QGroupBox* group_widget = new QGroupBox("GROUPNAME", w);
 QVBoxLayout*  group_layout = new QVBoxLayout;
 group_widget->setLayout(group_layout);
 group_layout->addWidget((QLabel*)new QLabel(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>here1"));
 group_layout->addWidget((QLabel*)new QLabel("here2"));

 QVBoxLayout*  gl = new QVBoxLayout;
 gl->addWidget(group_widget);

 main_window->setCentralWidget(node_tab_widget);
 main_window->show();
 return app.exec();
}
```

which add the QTabWidget `node_tab_widget` as central widget, with a tab `TAB`.

The tab contain the QGroupBox `GROUPNAME` with the two labels (vertical aligned)

Comment: As I said, the code does what it should, but the size of what is displayed is wrong: the tab widget ends up as a very little square on the top right corner of three bug mason window, and the two labels do not fit in it. Out looks as if the size liquidation

Comment: It looks as the size calculation is wrong... Sorry, writing from a smart phone

Comment: Compiling your code (with Qt 4.8) I get a window with the tab widget in the top left corner, with size 500x400. The tab has the GROUPNAME widget inside, and  the groupbox has the labels inside. Is looks ok to me. Which widget has the wrong size ? Can you post a screenshot ?

Comment: Yes, the setCentralWidget call was missing. sorry about that, I dropped it when puning my program. When calling it, the size is correct. The bad new is that it is called in main main program

Comment: So my pruned version did not reproduce the real problem... :-(
I may post some more...
Many thanks for taking the time to look at it.